# How does the follow user part work like in Instagram?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have two firestore collections in my app, "users" and "posts". Now I'm trying to create the third collection "userFeed" where all the posts of the followed users can be stored. How can i follow the users like in Instagram so that all the followed users' posts are stored in the 'userFeed' collection? How to query for following a user in a way that his future posts appear in the current user's 'userFeed'?

All the users have to sign with firebase auth so all users have a UID. How do i make the follow user query?

Comment: first you need a new collections  named user-follower
so store the users ids that follower or followed

Comment: alright..so i save the UIDs of the follower and followed. How does this show the posts of the users that are followed?

Comment: Join post and users collections and filter by by UIDS . if you want any code write your code and i will add complate of your code

Comment: @crazyroxx, Did you see this [similar post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068295/how-do-i-fetch-posts-of-users-that-the-current-signed-in-user-is-following#answer-59071335) I believe similar implementation is being attempted and although the response was in JavaScript, the basic principle is the same

Comment: @oakinlaja I am seeing now.. working on it ..thank you.

Comment: Great! I will add that as an answer, so that others with the same concern can reference the post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the same concern was raised and addressed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068295/how-do-i-fetch-posts-of-users-that-the-current-signed-in-user-is-following#answer-59071335). Although the response was in Javascript, the basic principle is the same.